# Multiple file upload with angular being deleted before sending files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple files to server.

The file is being stored in a variable.

When I click upload the client is sending that variable empty.

Here is my html

```
<div class = "control-group form-group col-md-12"
    ng-class = "{'has-error':newAsset.OSGImages.$invalid && newAsset.OSGImages.$dirty}" ng-if = "showUploadFile(4)">
      <label>OSG Images (max 3 MB)</label>
      <input type="file" multiple ngf-select="" ng-model="newAssetForm.OSGImages" name = "OSGImages" ngf-max-size="3 MB"> 
       <p ng-repeat="image in newAssetForm.OSGImages">
         {{image.name}}
       </p>
      <span class = "help-block has-error" ng-if="newAsset.OSGImages.$dirty">
      </span>
    </div>
```

Here is my js code:

```
enter code var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.newAssetForm.OSGImages[0]);
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/api/uploadAsset',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                data: {
                    'projectId': $scope.projectId,
                    'loadValueType' : $scope.newAssetForm.loadValueType,
                    'outputVideoLink': $scope.newAssetForm.outputVideoLink,
                    'isActive': $scope.newAssetForm.isActive,
                    'PImageSet': PImageSet,
                    inputImageUrl: $scope.newAssetForm.inputImageUrl,
                    markerPattFile: $scope.newAssetForm.markerPattFile,
                    cinema: $scope.newAssetForm.cinema,
                    objFile: $scope.newAssetForm.objFile,
                    mtlFile: $scope.newAssetForm.mtlFile,
                    PImage: $scope.newAssetForm.PImage,
                    osgFile: $scope.newAssetForm.OSGFile,
                    osgImage: e.target.result,
                },
            })
            .then(function onSuccess(result){
                $scope.$emit('create_asset', result.data);
                $modalInstance.close();
            })
```

I tried uploading with postman and the server is getting the files.

Also, the console logs print the files correctly.

Why the client is sending empty variable?

Comment: Which variable is empty?

Comment: I'm afraid `ng-model` doesn't work with input file type. You can try google `ngModel file input` and try out the solutions.

Comment: Before sending the upload, I can print the osgImage using console.log. It seems that the problem is when sending.

Comment: You have to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to upload multipart/form-data (with binary data) via ajax.

Comment: I'm not sending binary data. When I upload with postman I send it as "multipart/form-data" and it works.